# Using Bootbox to show a datatable in a pop-up

Tags: datatables, bootbox

I have the following JS function which shows a list of dates in a pop-up.

This function is called after an AJAX call that returns the required data.

```
function Show(currentSchedule) {
    var scheduleDates = currentSchedule.Dates.join(", ");

    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Preview",
        message: "<div class='row'><div class='box'>" + scheduleDates + "</div></div>"
    });
}
```

This will be called on a button click and it shows the dates as comma separated values.

To show this in a tabular format, I looked at Datatables.js library.

It requires a template table to be present into which the desired data will be injected. That works fine when you are showing the data on a page.

```
<table style="width:100%" id="previewTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date(s)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

What I am not able to figure out is a way to show the table in the pop-up instead of a page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Highlights**

Table is stored in a hidden `<div>` as a template. I'm cloning the template in order to set a unique ID `example`.

```js
var container = $('#example-container').clone();
container.find('table').attr('id', 'example');
```

---

Using `show: false` to hide dialog initially. This is needed so we could add DataTables initialization function once dialog is shown.

```js
var box = bootbox.dialog({
   show: false,
   message: container.html(),
   // ...
});
```

---

Handle event when dialog is shown to initialize DataTables.

```
box.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
   $('#example').DataTable(); 
});
```

---

Show dialog.

```
box.modal('show');
```

**Demo**

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-show').on('click', function(){
      var container = $('#example-container').clone();
      container.find('table').attr('id', 'example');

      var box = bootbox.dialog({
        show: false,
        message: container.html(),
        title: "DataTables in a Bootbox",
        buttons: {
          ok: {
            label: "OK",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function() {
              console.log('OK Button');
            }
          },
          cancel: {
            label: "Cancel",
            className: "btn-default"
          }
        }
      });
      
      box.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
         $('#example').DataTable(); 
      });
      
      box.modal('show'); 
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
  <button id="btn-show" class="btn btn-primary">Show Dialog</button>
</div>
<div id="example-container" style="display:none">
   <table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
   
     <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </tfoot>
   
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2011/04/25</td>
         <td>$320,800</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2011/07/25</td>
         <td>$170,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2009/01/12</td>
         <td>$86,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
         <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2012/03/29</td>
         <td>$433,060</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Airi Satou</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>33</td>
         <td>2008/11/28</td>
         <td>$162,700</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2012/12/02</td>
         <td>$372,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2012/08/06</td>
         <td>$137,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>55</td>
         <td>2010/10/14</td>
         <td>$327,900</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2009/09/15</td>
         <td>$205,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sonya Frost</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2008/12/13</td>
         <td>$103,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jena Gaines</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2008/12/19</td>
         <td>$90,560</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
         <td>Support Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2013/03/03</td>
         <td>$342,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Charde Marshall</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2008/10/16</td>
         <td>$470,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
         <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2012/12/18</td>
         <td>$313,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>19</td>
         <td>2010/03/17</td>
         <td>$385,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Silva</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2012/11/27</td>
         <td>$198,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Paul Byrd</td>
         <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2010/06/09</td>
         <td>$725,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gloria Little</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2009/04/10</td>
         <td>$237,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bradley Greer</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2012/10/13</td>
         <td>$132,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Dai Rios</td>
         <td>Personnel Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>35</td>
         <td>2012/09/26</td>
         <td>$217,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
         <td>Development Lead</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2011/09/03</td>
         <td>$345,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Yuri Berry</td>
         <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>40</td>
         <td>2009/06/25</td>
         <td>$675,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Caesar Vance</td>
         <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2011/12/12</td>
         <td>$106,450</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Doris Wilder</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2010/09/20</td>
         <td>$85,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
         <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/10/09</td>
         <td>$1,200,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>42</td>
         <td>2010/12/22</td>
         <td>$92,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2010/11/14</td>
         <td>$357,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2011/06/07</td>
         <td>$206,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Fiona Green</td>
         <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>48</td>
         <td>2010/03/11</td>
         <td>$850,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shou Itou</td>
         <td>Regional Marketing</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>20</td>
         <td>2011/08/14</td>
         <td>$163,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michelle House</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2011/06/02</td>
         <td>$95,400</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Suki Burks</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>53</td>
         <td>2009/10/22</td>
         <td>$114,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
         <td>Technical Author</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/05/07</td>
         <td>$145,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
         <td>Team Leader</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2008/10/26</td>
         <td>$235,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Martena Mccray</td>
         <td>Post-Sales support</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/03/09</td>
         <td>$324,050</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Unity Butler</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/12/09</td>
         <td>$85,675</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/12/16</td>
         <td>$164,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
         <td>Secretary</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2010/02/12</td>
         <td>$109,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
         <td>Financial Controller</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>62</td>
         <td>2009/02/14</td>
         <td>$452,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2008/12/11</td>
         <td>$136,200</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
         <td>Director</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>65</td>
         <td>2008/09/26</td>
         <td>$645,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Olivia Liang</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2011/02/03</td>
         <td>$234,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bruno Nash</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2011/05/03</td>
         <td>$163,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2009/08/19</td>
         <td>$139,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Thor Walton</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2013/08/11</td>
         <td>$98,540</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Finn Camacho</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/07/07</td>
         <td>$87,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
         <td>Data Coordinator</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2012/04/09</td>
         <td>$138,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2010/01/04</td>
         <td>$125,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>56</td>
         <td>2012/06/01</td>
         <td>$115,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
         <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2013/02/01</td>
         <td>$75,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cara Stevens</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/12/06</td>
         <td>$145,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hermione Butler</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2011/03/21</td>
         <td>$356,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Lael Greer</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2009/02/27</td>
         <td>$103,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2010/07/14</td>
         <td>$86,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shad Decker</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/11/13</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Bruce</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>29</td>
         <td>2011/06/27</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Donna Snider</td>
         <td>Customer Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/01/25</td>
         <td>$112,000</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```